# Having a Python dictionary with 2 values find XML elements that doesn't have does values in defined Tags

Tags: python, xml, dictionary

I have a dictonary with values like:

```
{'el salto': ['durango'], 'durango': ['durango', 'urbana'], 'jimenez': ['chihuahua'], 'gomez palacio': ['durango', 'urbana'], 'chihuahua': ['chihuahua', 'urbana'], 'santiago papasquiaro': ['durango'], 'lerdo': ['durango'], 'matamoros': ['coahuila'], 'nuevo ideal': ['durango'], 'canatlan': ['durango'], 'hidalgo del parral': ['chihuahua', 'urbana'], 'torreon': ['coahuila'], 'cuauhtemoc': ['chihuahua', 'urbana'], 'delicias': ['chihuahua', 'urbana', 'chihuahua'], 'villa union': ['durango'], 'vicente guerrero': ['durango'], 'meoqui': ['chihuahua'], 'guadalupe victoria': ['durango'], 'saucillo': ['chihuahua'], 'nuevo casas grandes': ['chihuahua', 'urbana'], 'camargo': ['chihuahua'], 'nombre de dios': ['durango'], 'juarez': ['chihuahua', 'urbana'], 'francisco i. madero': ['durango'], 'san pedro': ['coahuila']}
```

(some has 'urbana' in it, some doesn't)

I need to filter results where key is in tag "d_ciudad" of the element and then check if dictionary key has the same value as the tag "d_estado" in the element and if 'urbana' is defined in the key of the dictionary, filter by this too, I am trying the following code:

```
from xml.etree.ElementTree import ElementTree
import csv

tree = ElementTree()
my_dict = dict()

# Test input
tree.parse("sample_in.xml")
with open('file1.csv', 'rb') as csv_file:
    reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
    my_dict = dict(reader)

for node in tree.findall('.//data'):
    # Remove node if the name attribute value is not in inputID
    if not node.attrib.get('d_ciudad').lower() in my_dict:
        tree.getroot().remove(node)
    else:
        if not node.attrib.get('d_estado').lower() in my_dict[node.attrib.get('d_ciudad')]:
            tree.getroot().remove(node)
        else:
            if 'urbana' in my_dict[node.attrib.get('d_ciudad').lower()]:
                if node.attrib.get('d_zona').lower() != 'Urbano':
                    tree.getroot().remove(node)


# Do what you want with the modified xml
tree.write('sample_out.xml')
```

I am getting a bigger file than it was and with lots of ns0: in it.
The XML are like:

INPUT

```
<NewDataSet><xsd:schema targetNamespace="NewDataSet" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:sqltypes="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/sqltypes" elementFormDefault="qualified"><xsd:import namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/sqltypes" schemaLocation="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/sqltypes/sqltypes.xsd"/><xsd:element name="table"><xsd:complexType><xsd:sequence><xsd:element name="d_codigo" minOccurs="0"><xsd:simpleType><xsd:restriction base="sqltypes:nvarchar" sqltypes:localeId="3082" sqltypes:sqlCompareOptions="IgnoreCase IgnoreKanaType IgnoreWidth"><xsd:maxLength value="5"/></xsd:restriction></xsd:simpleType></xsd:element><xsd:element name="d_asenta" minOccurs="0"><xsd:simpleType><xsd:restriction base="sqltypes:nvarchar" sqltypes:localeId="3082" sqltypes:sqlCompareOptions="IgnoreCase IgnoreKanaType IgnoreWidth"><xsd:maxLength value="60"/></xsd:restriction></xsd:simpleType></xsd:element><xsd:element name="d_tipo_asenta" minOccurs="0"><xsd:simpleType><xsd:restriction base="sqltypes:nvarchar" sqltypes:localeId="3082" sqltypes:sqlCompareOptions="IgnoreCase IgnoreKanaType IgnoreWidth"><xsd:maxLength value="40"/></xsd:restriction></xsd:simpleType></xsd:element><xsd:element name="D_mnpio" minOccurs="0"><xsd:simpleType><xsd:restriction base="sqltypes:nvarchar" sqltypes:localeId="3082" sqltypes:sqlCompareOptions="IgnoreCase IgnoreKanaType IgnoreWidth"><xsd:maxLength value="50"/></xsd:restriction></xsd:simpleType></xsd:element><xsd:element name="d_estado" minOccurs="0"><xsd:simpleType><xsd:restriction base="sqltypes:nvarchar" sqltypes:localeId="3082" sqltypes:sqlCompareOptions="IgnoreCase IgnoreKanaType IgnoreWidth"><xsd:maxLength value="35"/></xsd:restriction></xsd:simpleType></xsd:element><xsd:element name="d_ciudad" minOccurs="0"><xsd:simpleType><xsd:restriction base="sqltypes:nvarchar" sqltypes:localeId="3082" sqltypes:sqlCompareOptions="IgnoreCase IgnoreKanaType IgnoreWidth"><xsd:maxLength value="50"/></xsd:restriction></xsd:simpleType></xsd:element><xsd:element name="d_CP" minOccurs="0"><xsd:simpleType><xsd:restriction base="sqltypes:nvarchar" sqltypes:localeId="3082" sqltypes:sqlCompareOptions="IgnoreCase IgnoreKanaType IgnoreWidth"><xsd:maxLength value="5"/></xsd:restriction></xsd:simpleType></xsd:element><xsd:element name="c_estado" minOccurs="0"><xsd:simpleType><xsd:restriction base="sqltypes:nvarchar" sqltypes:localeId="3082" sqltypes:sqlCompareOptions="IgnoreCase IgnoreKanaType IgnoreWidth"><xsd:maxLength value="2"/></xsd:restriction></xsd:simpleType></xsd:element><xsd:element name="c_oficina" minOccurs="0"><xsd:simpleType><xsd:restriction base="sqltypes:nvarchar" sqltypes:localeId="3082" sqltypes:sqlCompareOptions="IgnoreCase IgnoreKanaType IgnoreWidth"><xsd:maxLength value="5"/></xsd:restriction></xsd:simpleType></xsd:element><xsd:element name="c_CP" minOccurs="0"><xsd:simpleType><xsd:restriction base="sqltypes:nvarchar" sqltypes:localeId="3082" sqltypes:sqlCompareOptions="IgnoreCase IgnoreKanaType IgnoreWidth"><xsd:maxLength value="5"/></xsd:restriction></xsd:simpleType></xsd:element><xsd:element name="c_tipo_asenta" minOccurs="0"><xsd:simpleType><xsd:restriction base="sqltypes:nvarchar" sqltypes:localeId="3082" sqltypes:sqlCompareOptions="IgnoreCase IgnoreKanaType IgnoreWidth"><xsd:maxLength value="2"/></xsd:restriction></xsd:simpleType></xsd:element><xsd:element name="c_mnpio" minOccurs="0"><xsd:simpleType><xsd:restriction base="sqltypes:nvarchar" sqltypes:localeId="3082" sqltypes:sqlCompareOptions="IgnoreCase IgnoreKanaType IgnoreWidth"><xsd:maxLength value="3"/></xsd:restriction></xsd:simpleType></xsd:element><xsd:element name="id_asenta_cpcons" minOccurs="0"><xsd:simpleType><xsd:restriction base="sqltypes:nvarchar" sqltypes:localeId="3082" sqltypes:sqlCompareOptions="IgnoreCase IgnoreKanaType IgnoreWidth"><xsd:maxLength value="4"/></xsd:restriction></xsd:simpleType></xsd:element><xsd:element name="d_zona" minOccurs="0"><xsd:simpleType><xsd:restriction base="sqltypes:nvarchar" sqltypes:localeId="3082" sqltypes:sqlCompareOptions="IgnoreCase IgnoreKanaType IgnoreWidth"><xsd:maxLength value="40"/></xsd:restriction></xsd:simpleType></xsd:element><xsd:element name="c_cve_ciudad" minOccurs="0"><xsd:simpleType><xsd:restriction base="sqltypes:nvarchar" sqltypes:localeId="3082" sqltypes:sqlCompareOptions="IgnoreCase IgnoreKanaType IgnoreWidth"><xsd:maxLength value="2"/></xsd:restriction></xsd:simpleType></xsd:element></xsd:sequence></xsd:complexType></xsd:element></xsd:schema><table xmlns="NewDataSet"><d_codigo>01000</d_codigo><d_asenta>San Ángel</d_asenta><d_tipo_asenta>Colonia</d_tipo_asenta><D_mnpio>Álvaro Obregón</D_mnpio><d_estado>Ciudad de México</d_estado><d_ciudad>Ciudad de México</d_ciudad><d_CP>01001</d_CP><c_estado>09</c_estado><c_oficina>01001</c_oficina><c_CP></c_CP><c_tipo_asenta>09</c_tipo_asenta><c_mnpio>010</c_mnpio><id_asenta_cpcons>0001</id_asenta_cpcons><d_zona>Urbano</d_zona><c_cve_ciudad>01</c_cve_ciudad></table><table xmlns="NewDataSet"><d_codigo>01010</d_codigo><d_asenta>Los Alpes</d_asenta><d_tipo_asenta>Colonia</d_tipo_asenta><D_mnpio>Álvaro Obregón</D_mnpio><d_estado>Ciudad de México</d_estado><d_ciudad>Ciudad de México</d_ciudad><d_CP>01001</d_CP><c_estado>09</c_estado><c_oficina>01001</c_oficina><c_CP></c_CP><c_tipo_asenta>09</c_tipo_asenta><c_mnpio>010</c_mnpio><id_asenta_cpcons>0005</id_asenta_cpcons><d_zona>Urbano</d_zona><c_cve_ciudad>01</c_cve_ciudad></table><table xmlns="NewDataSet"><d_codigo>01020</d_codigo><d_asenta>Guadalupe Inn</d_asenta><d_tipo_asenta>Colonia</d_tipo_asenta><D_mnpio>Álvaro Obregón</D_mnpio><d_estado>Ciudad de México</d_estado><d_ciudad>Ciudad de México</d_ciudad><d_CP>01001</d_CP><c_estado>09</c_estado><c_oficina>01001</c_oficina><c_CP></c_CP><c_tipo_asenta>09</c_tipo_asenta><c_mnpio>010</c_mnpio><id_asenta_cpcons>0006</id_asenta_cpcons><d_zona>Urbano</d_zona><c_cve_ciudad>01</c_cve_ciudad></table><table xmlns="NewDataSet"><d_codigo>01030</d_codigo><d_asenta>Florida</d_asenta><d_tipo_asenta>Colonia</d_tipo_asenta><D_mnpio>Álvaro Obregón</D_mnpio><d_estado>Ciudad de México</d_estado><d_ciudad>Ciudad de México</d_ciudad><d_CP>01001</d_CP><c_estado>09</c_estado><c_oficina>01001</c_oficina><c_CP></c_CP><c_tipo_asenta>09</c_tipo_asenta><c_mnpio>010</c_mnpio><id_asenta_cpcons>0010</id_asenta_cpcons><d_zona>Urbano</d_zona><c_cve_ciudad>01</c_cve_ciudad></table><table xmlns="NewDataSet"><d_codigo>01030</d_codigo><d_asenta>Axotla</d_asenta><d_tipo_asenta>Pueblo</d_tipo_asenta><D_mnpio>Álvaro Obregón</D_mnpio><d_estado>Ciudad de México</d_estado><d_ciudad>Ciudad de México</d_ciudad><d_CP>01001</d_CP><c_estado>09</c_estado><c_oficina>01001</c_oficina><c_CP></c_CP><c_tipo_asenta>28</c_tipo_asenta><c_mnpio>010</c_mnpio><id_asenta_cpcons>0009</id_asenta_cpcons><d_zona>Urbano</d_zona><c_cve_ciudad>01</c_cve_ciudad></table><table xmlns="NewDataSet"><d_codigo>01040</d_codigo><d_asenta>Campestre</d_asenta><d_tipo_asenta>Colonia</d_tipo_asenta><D_mnpio>Álvaro Obregón</D_mnpio><d_estado>Ciudad de México</d_estado><d_ciudad>Ciudad de México</d_ciudad><d_CP>01001</d_CP><c_estado>09</c_estado><c_oficina>01001</c_oficina><c_CP></c_CP><c_tipo_asenta>09</c_tipo_asenta><c_mnpio>010</c_mnpio><id_asenta_cpcons>0012</id_asenta_cpcons><d_zona>Urbano</d_zona><c_cve_ciudad>01</c_cve_ciudad></table><table xmlns="NewDataSet"><d_codigo>01048</d_codigo><d_asenta>Las Águilas</d_asenta><d_tipo_asenta>Unidad habitacional</d_tipo_asenta><D_mnpio>Álvaro Obregón</D_mnpio><d_estado>Ciudad de México</d_estado><d_ciudad>Ciudad de México</d_ciudad><d_CP>01001</d_CP><c_estado>09</c_estado><c_oficina>01001</c_oficina><c_CP></c_CP><c_tipo_asenta>31</c_tipo_asenta><c_mnpio>010</c_mnpio><id_asenta_cpcons>0013</id_asenta_cpcons><d_zona>Urbano</d_zona><c_cve_ciudad>01</c_cve_ciudad></table><table xmlns="NewDataSet"><d_codigo>01049</d_codigo><d_asenta>Tlacopac</d_asenta><d_tipo_asenta>Pueblo</d_tipo_asenta><D_mnpio>Álvaro Obregón</D_mnpio><d_estado>Ciudad de México</d_estado><d_ciudad>Ciudad de México</d_ciudad><d_CP>01001</d_CP><c_estado>09</c_estado><c_oficina>01001</c_oficina><c_CP></c_CP><c_tipo_asenta>28</c_tipo_asenta><c_mnpio>010</c_mnpio><id_asenta_cpcons>0014</id_asenta_cpcons><d_zona>Urbano</d_zona><c_cve_ciudad>01</c_cve_ciudad></table><table xmlns="NewDataSet"><d_codigo>01050</d_codigo><d_asenta>Ex-Hacienda de Guadalupe Chimalistac</d_asenta><d_tipo_asenta>Colonia</d_tipo_asenta><D_mnpio>Álvaro Obregón</D_mnpio><d_estado>Ciudad de México</d_estado><d_ciudad>Ciudad de México</d_ciudad><d_CP>01001</d_CP><c_estado>09</c_estado><c_oficina>01001</c_oficina><c_CP></c_CP><c_tipo_asenta>09</c_tipo_asenta><c_mnpio>010</c_mnpio><id_asenta_cpcons>0016</id_asenta_cpcons><d_zona>Urbano</d_zona><c_cve_ciudad>01</c_cve_ciudad></table><table xmlns="NewDataSet"><d_codigo>01060</d_codigo><d_asenta>San Ángel Inn</d_asenta><d_tipo_asenta>Colonia</d_tipo_asenta><D_mnpio>Álvaro Obregón</D_mnpio><d_estado>Ciudad de México</d_estado><d_ciudad>Ciudad de México</d_ciudad><d_CP>01001</d_CP><c_estado>09</c_estado><c_oficina>01001</c_oficina><c_CP></c_CP><c_tipo_asenta>09</c_tipo_asenta><c_mnpio>010</c_mnpio><id_asenta_cpcons>0018</id_asenta_cpcons><d_zona>Urbano</d_zona><c_cve_ciudad>01</c_cve_ciudad></table>
```

OUTPUT:

```
<NewDataSet xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/sqltypes" xmlns:ns2="NewDataSet" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="NewDataSet"><xs:import namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/sqltypes" schemaLocation="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/sqltypes/sqltypes.xsd" /><xs:element name="table"><xs:complexType><xs:sequence><xs:element minOccurs="0" name="d_codigo"><xs:simpleType><xs:restriction base="sqltypes:nvarchar" ns1:localeId="3082" ns1:sqlCompareOptions="IgnoreCase IgnoreKanaType IgnoreWidth"><xs:maxLength value="5" /></xs:restriction></xs:simpleType></xs:element><xs:element minOccurs="0" name="d_asenta"><xs:simpleType><xs:restriction base="sqltypes:nvarchar" ns1:localeId="3082" ns1:sqlCompareOptions="IgnoreCase IgnoreKanaType IgnoreWidth"><xs:maxLength value="60" /></xs:restriction></xs:simpleType></xs:element><xs:element minOccurs="0" name="d_tipo_asenta"><xs:simpleType><xs:restriction base="sqltypes:nvarchar" ns1:localeId="3082" ns1:sqlCompareOptions="IgnoreCase IgnoreKanaType IgnoreWidth"><xs:maxLength value="40" /></xs:restriction></xs:simpleType></xs:element><xs:element minOccurs="0" name="D_mnpio"><xs:simpleType><xs:restriction base="sqltypes:nvarchar" ns1:localeId="3082" ns1:sqlCompareOptions="IgnoreCase IgnoreKanaType IgnoreWidth"><xs:maxLength value="50" /></xs:restriction></xs:simpleType></xs:element><xs:element minOccurs="0" name="d_estado"><xs:simpleType><xs:restriction base="sqltypes:nvarchar" ns1:localeId="3082" ns1:sqlCompareOptions="IgnoreCase IgnoreKanaType IgnoreWidth"><xs:maxLength value="35" /></xs:restriction></xs:simpleType></xs:element><xs:element minOccurs="0" name="d_ciudad"><xs:simpleType><xs:restriction base="sqltypes:nvarchar" ns1:localeId="3082" ns1:sqlCompareOptions="IgnoreCase IgnoreKanaType IgnoreWidth"><xs:maxLength value="50" /></xs:restriction></xs:simpleType></xs:element><xs:element minOccurs="0" name="d_CP"><xs:simpleType><xs:restriction base="sqltypes:nvarchar" ns1:localeId="3082" ns1:sqlCompareOptions="IgnoreCase IgnoreKanaType IgnoreWidth"><xs:maxLength value="5" /></xs:restriction></xs:simpleType></xs:element><xs:element minOccurs="0" name="c_estado"><xs:simpleType><xs:restriction base="sqltypes:nvarchar" ns1:localeId="3082" ns1:sqlCompareOptions="IgnoreCase IgnoreKanaType IgnoreWidth"><xs:maxLength value="2" /></xs:restriction></xs:simpleType></xs:element><xs:element minOccurs="0" name="c_oficina"><xs:simpleType><xs:restriction base="sqltypes:nvarchar" ns1:localeId="3082" ns1:sqlCompareOptions="IgnoreCase IgnoreKanaType IgnoreWidth"><xs:maxLength value="5" /></xs:restriction></xs:simpleType></xs:element><xs:element minOccurs="0" name="c_CP"><xs:simpleType><xs:restriction base="sqltypes:nvarchar" ns1:localeId="3082" ns1:sqlCompareOptions="IgnoreCase IgnoreKanaType IgnoreWidth"><xs:maxLength value="5" /></xs:restriction></xs:simpleType></xs:element><xs:element minOccurs="0" name="c_tipo_asenta"><xs:simpleType><xs:restriction base="sqltypes:nvarchar" ns1:localeId="3082" ns1:sqlCompareOptions="IgnoreCase IgnoreKanaType IgnoreWidth"><xs:maxLength value="2" /></xs:restriction></xs:simpleType></xs:element><xs:element minOccurs="0" name="c_mnpio"><xs:simpleType><xs:restriction base="sqltypes:nvarchar" ns1:localeId="3082" ns1:sqlCompareOptions="IgnoreCase IgnoreKanaType IgnoreWidth"><xs:maxLength value="3" /></xs:restriction></xs:simpleType></xs:element><xs:element minOccurs="0" name="id_asenta_cpcons"><xs:simpleType><xs:restriction base="sqltypes:nvarchar" ns1:localeId="3082" ns1:sqlCompareOptions="IgnoreCase IgnoreKanaType IgnoreWidth"><xs:maxLength value="4" /></xs:restriction></xs:simpleType></xs:element><xs:element minOccurs="0" name="d_zona"><xs:simpleType><xs:restriction base="sqltypes:nvarchar" ns1:localeId="3082" ns1:sqlCompareOptions="IgnoreCase IgnoreKanaType IgnoreWidth"><xs:maxLength value="40" /></xs:restriction></xs:simpleType></xs:element><xs:element minOccurs="0" name="c_cve_ciudad"><xs:simpleType><xs:restriction base="sqltypes:nvarchar" ns1:localeId="3082" ns1:sqlCompareOptions="IgnoreCase IgnoreKanaType IgnoreWidth"><xs:maxLength value="2" /></xs:restriction></xs:simpleType></xs:element></xs:sequence></xs:complexType></xs:element></xs:schema><ns2:table><ns2:d_codigo>01000</ns2:d_codigo><ns2:d_asenta>San &#193;ngel</ns2:d_asenta><ns2:d_tipo_asenta>Colonia</ns2:d_tipo_asenta><ns2:D_mnpio>&#193;lvaro Obreg&#243;n</ns2:D_mnpio><ns2:d_estado>Ciudad de M&#233;xico</ns2:d_estado><ns2:d_ciudad>Ciudad de M&#233;xico</ns2:d_ciudad><ns2:d_CP>01001</ns2:d_CP><ns2:c_estado>09</ns2:c_estado><ns2:c_oficina>01001</ns2:c_oficina><ns2:c_CP /><ns2:c_tipo_asenta>09</ns2:c_tipo_asenta><ns2:c_mnpio>010</ns2:c_mnpio><ns2:id_asenta_cpcons>0001</ns2:id_asenta_cpcons><ns2:d_zona>Urbano</ns2:d_zona><ns2:c_cve_ciudad>01</ns2:c_cve_ciudad></ns2:table><ns2:table><ns2:d_codigo>01010</ns2:d_codigo><ns2:d_asenta>Los Alpes</ns2:d_asenta><ns2:d_tipo_asenta>Colonia</ns2:d_tipo_asenta><ns2:D_mnpio>&#193;lvaro Obreg&#243;n</ns2:D_mnpio><ns2:d_estado>Ciudad de M&#233;xico</ns2:d_estado><ns2:d_ciudad>Ciudad de M&#233;xico</ns2:d_ciudad><ns2:d_CP>01001</ns2:d_CP><ns2:c_estado>09</ns2:c_estado><ns2:c_oficina>01001</ns2:c_oficina><ns2:c_CP /><ns2:c_tipo_asenta>09</ns2:c_tipo_asenta><ns2:c_mnpio>010</ns2:c_mnpio><ns2:id_asenta_cpcons>0005</ns2:id_asenta_cpcons><ns2:d_zona>Urbano</ns2:d_zona><ns2:c_cve_ciudad>01</ns2:c_cve_ciudad></ns2:table><ns2:table><ns2:d_codigo>01020</ns2:d_codigo><ns2:d_asenta>Guadalupe Inn</ns2:d_asenta><ns2:d_tipo_asenta>Colonia</ns2:d_tipo_asenta><ns2:D_mnpio>&#193;lvaro Obreg&#243;n</ns2:D_mnpio><ns2:d_estado>Ciudad de M&#233;xico</ns2:d_estado><ns2:d_ciudad>Ciudad de M&#233;xico</ns2:d_ciudad><ns2:d_CP>01001</ns2:d_CP><ns2:c_estado>09</ns2:c_estado><ns2:c_oficina>01001</ns2:c_oficina><ns2:c_CP /><ns2:c_tipo_asenta>09</ns2:c_tipo_asenta><ns2:c_mnpio>010</ns2:c_mnpio><ns2:id_asenta_cpcons>0006</ns2:id_asenta_cpcons><ns2:d_zona>Urbano</ns2:d_zona><ns2:c_cve_ciudad>01</ns2:c_cve_ciudad></ns2:table>
```

Comment: Please post the contents of `sample_in.xml` and `sample_out.xml` (I'm unsure if the XML at the end of your question is the input or the output). Also, please include the output you're expecting.

Comment: thanks for noting it, I already edited the answer. Output should be a filtered XML where valures not in my_dict are removed

Comment: Just to clarify, if (for example) the value in `d_ciudad` is wrong, do you want to just delete the `d_ciudad` element or delete the whole `table` element that includes it?

Comment: thanks for checking this out, the whole table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're a bit confused about XML terminology. I recommend reading [the relevant section of the Wikipedia article on XML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML#Key_terminology) to learn some basics. Basically, there are elements (such as `<table>`), attributes (such as `ns1:localeId="3082"`), and namespaces which are effectively prefixes to elements and attributes. Additionally, elements can be nested inside of other elements and then you can say some elements have children or others have parents.

In your case, it looks like you had the right idea with your code except you were confusing some terminology (and possibly how to use the XML API in Python). Below is a slightly modified version of your code which should work:

```
# Initialize my_dict just like you were doing up here.
tree.parse("sample_in.xml")

for table in tree.findall('.//{NewDataSet}table'):
    # If any of the checks fail, delete the whole table element.
    ciudad = table.find('./{NewDataSet}d_ciudad').text.lower().strip()
    if ciudad not in my_dict:
        print('ciudad: %s' % ciudad)
        tree.getroot().remove(table)
        continue

    estado = table.find('./{NewDataSet}d_estado').text.lower().strip()
    print('test: %s' % estado)
    if estado not in my_dict[ciudad]:
        print('estado: %s' % estado)
        tree.getroot().remove(table)
        continue

    if 'urbana' in my_dict[ciudad]:
        zona = table.find('./{NewDataSet}d_zona').text.lower().strip()
        if zona != 'urbano':
            print('zona: %s' % zona)
            tree.getroot().remove(table)
            continue

# Do what you want with the modified xml
tree.write('sample_out.xml')
```

You're probably only interested in the modified calls to `find` and `findall`. Those take [basic XPath expressions](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xpath-support) and return the first node or all of the nodes that match. Notably, the `{NewDataSet}` portion is specifying a namespace and the work that comes after is (in this case) the name of an element.

<sub>I also structurally changed the code a bit so your `if` statements were less nested but that is purely cosmetic.</sub>

Comment: thanks for your explanation and correction, the code seems to start working but there comes a moment where I get this error:      `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/tobe/PycharmProjects/codigos_postales/main2.py", line 14, in <module>
    ciudad = table.find('./{NewDataSet}d_ciudad').text.lower().strip()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'`
How to track this error and what do I have to do to skip it if it can be skiped

Comment: That means one of your tables is missing the `d_ciudad` child element. Do you want to delete those tables or just leave that table alone and go on to the next one?